# Как заавтовайрить внутренние зависимости класса созданного в @scheduled методе

Tags: java, spring-boot

Собственно сабж:
есть класс Jobs
там метод помеченный @scheduled
в методе создается инстанс класса и у него дергается метод, запускающий логику
в созданном классе автовайрится сервайс с которым дальше логика и отрабатывает

сейчас ничего не автовайрится..
как мне подсказали, во всех инстансах создаваемых вне основного контекста спринга (а @scheduled именно этот случай) не будут доступны внутренние зависимости. 
Подскажите как это обойти или перестроить приложение

Comment: Я правильно понял что у вас есть метод, внутри которого создается новый объект, а внутри этого класса этого объекта происходит автовайринг какого-то поля?

Comment: да, все правильно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Либо вместо создания инстанса получайте его из контекста, либо получайте зависимости в классе Jobs и передавайте их в конструктор.

Comment: ну вот у меня сразу мысль и возникла инжектить их сверху. Но показалось каким-то костылем)